# Setting include path in PHP intermittently fails

Tags: php, include-path

I have tried both of :

```
ini_set('include_path', '.:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php5/PEAR:lib:app/classes');
```

and also :

```
php_value include_path ".:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php5/PEAR:lib:app/classes"
```

in the .htaccess file.

Both methods actually **do work** but only intermittently. That is, they will work fine for about 37 pages requests and then fail about 42 pages requests resulting in an require() call to cause a fatal error effectively crashing the site.

I'm not even sure where to begin trying to find out what is going on!

---

@[cnote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836/setting-include-path-in-php-intermittently-fails-why#41877)

> Looks like you duplicated the current directory in your include path. Try removing one of the '.:' from your string.

The in script version was originally

```
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes');
```

and thus the .:.: was coming from the existing path:

```
ini_get('include_path')
```

I tried removing it anyway and the problem persists.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you get on the requests that fail? Are you sure a script isn't trying to include something that used to be in the same directory but moved to a subdirectory, or vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out the issue was related to a PHP bug in 5.2.5

Setting an "admin_flag" for include_path caused the include path to be empty in some requests, and Plesk sets an admin_flag in the default config for something or other. An update of PHP solved the issue.

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43677

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [set_include_path()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)?.  As a benefit this returns false on failure, allowing you to at least catch the occurence and generate some meaningful debug data.
Additionally, you should be using the constant `PATH_SEPARATOR` as it differs between windows / *nix.

As a specific example:

```
set_include_path('.' . PATH_SEPARATOR . './app/lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

(the get_include_path() on the end means whatever your ini / htaccess path is set to will remain)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you duplicated the current directory in your include path. Try removing one of the '.:' from your string.